# Dockerfile how to add localhost alias

Tags: docker

Dockerfile how to add localhost alias ?

Hi i need to add `localhost` alias in the `Dockerfile`
I do the following:

`RUN echo '127.0.0.1 locdev' >> /etc/hosts`

But when i then go to image bash console

```
$ docker exec -it my-image bash
```

and try to ping that host it does throw error

```
$ ping locdev
ping: unknown host
```

What `/etc/hosts` contains ?

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.4  62a5e2d10730
```

there is no other records

Does anyone know how can i do this ? I need to do this in `Dockerfile` as external service run this docker and i do not run it from command line.

In my case it is an `PHP` application, that is held in `Bitbucket` repository. There is a new feature called `PIPELINES`. It run application build on `Docker` image.

In my case this application connects to `mysql` server where i can not change config (it will break production). On that docker image i ahve set up `mysql` server. So `localhost` works, but i need to add this alias for `localhost` to not break production server;

`Dockerfile` fragment:

```
RUN \
 aliases="127.0.0.1 localhost locdev" &&\
 sed "1s/.*/$aliases/" /etc/hosts
RUN cat /etc/hosts
```

My `docker build` output example:

```
Step 10 : RUN aliases="127.0.0.1 localhost locdev" && sed "1s/.*/$aliases/" /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in 11ac105d632d
127.0.0.1 localhost locdev
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      383850eeb47b
 ---> 0248977e48bd
Removing intermediate container 11ac105d632d
Step 11 : RUN cat /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in 20fc2f40b5a9
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      383850eeb47b
 ---> c9e47ee296c5
Removing intermediate container 20fc2f40b5a9
Successfully built c9e47ee296c5
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102660/hosts-file-is-it-incorrect-to-have-the-same-ip-address-on-multiple-lines you are not supposed to have multiple lines pointing to 127.0.0.1. You should modify the existing localhost line by appending an alias

Comment: But `/etc/host` contains only that record i added

Comment: It should be `/etc/hosts` (note the `s` at the end)

Comment: so it does not work on `hosts` file it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Docker manages the `/etc/hosts` file for you, making changes to `/etc/hosts` isn't going to work.

You can, however, add additional hosts to Docker's DNS service discovery with the `--add-host` option when running `docker create` or `docker run`.

This is from the output of `docker run --help`:

```
  --add-host value              Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip) (default [])
```

Keep in mind, however, that 127.0.0.1 from inside a container will not take you to the container host, but will land you on the container since it has its own 127.0.0.1 interface.

The eth0 IP address of your docker host is routable from inside your container. You could use that in your `--add-host` argument. For example, if my Docker host is 192.168.1.43 on my local network, I could do `docker run --add-host locdev:192.168.1.43 ...`. At that point, `locdev` will resolve back to that ip from inside the container.

Comment: I need to do this in Dockerfile as external service run this docker and i do not run it from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Better than using the address from `eth0` (or other interface on your host), just use the address of the default gateway from inside your Docker container.  This is the address of the Docker-maintained bridge on your host to which the container is connected.  You can get this as:

```
ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}'
```

That will always be an address of your host.

Comment: The point is i need it to be alias for localhost as application config requires it and this images is for bitbucket pipelines

Comment: Would you update your question with more information about the configuration?  What is it that needs to connect to `localhost`?  Why can't it use another address?  Can you run a second container with `--net=container:...` that runs a *proxy* so that `localhost` connections will work as expected?